# Custom TimePickerRenderer is not firing the events to update the TimeProperty

Tags: c#, mobile, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I created a custom TimePicker and the renderers to android and iphone, with the objective to allow for that be nullable. As inspiration, was used the https://xamgirl.com/clearable-datepicker-in-xamarin-forms/

But, for some reason, the event is not firing when the time is set, thats happenen only in android, and more specific, back in android 8.1.

On shared project:

```
public class NullableTimePicker : TimePicker
    {
        public NullableTimePicker()
        {
            Time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
            NullableTime = null;

            Format = @"HH\:mm";
        }
        public string _originalFormat = null;

        public static readonly BindableProperty PlaceHolderProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PlaceHolder), typeof(string), typeof(NullableTimePicker), "  :  ");

        public string PlaceHolder
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(PlaceHolderProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(PlaceHolderProperty, value);
            }
        }


        public static readonly BindableProperty NullableTimeProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(NullableTime), typeof(TimeSpan?), typeof(NullableTimePicker), null, defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

        public TimeSpan? NullableTime
        {
            get { return (TimeSpan?)GetValue(NullableTimeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NullableTimeProperty, value); UpdateTime(); }
        }

        private void UpdateTime()
        {
            if (NullableTime != null)
            {
                if (_originalFormat != null)
                {
                    Format = _originalFormat;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Format = PlaceHolder;
            }

        }
        protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
        {
            base.OnBindingContextChanged();
            if (BindingContext != null)
            {
                _originalFormat = Format;
                UpdateTime();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

            if (propertyName == TimeProperty.PropertyName ||
                (
                    propertyName == IsFocusedProperty.PropertyName &&
                    !IsFocused &&
                    (Time == DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay)))
            {
                AssignValue();
            }

            if (propertyName == NullableTimeProperty.PropertyName && NullableTime.HasValue)
            {
                Time = NullableTime.Value;
                if (Time == DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay)
                {
                    //this code was done because when date selected is the actual date the"DateProperty" does not raise  
                    UpdateTime();
                }
            }
        }

        public void CleanTime()
        {
            NullableTime = null;
            UpdateTime();
        }
        public void AssignValue()
        {
            NullableTime = Time;
            UpdateTime();

        }
    }
```

On Android project:

```
public class NullableTimePickerRenderer : ViewRenderer<NullableTimePicker, EditText>
    {
        public NullableTimePickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        TimePickerDialog _dialog;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<NullableTimePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            this.SetNativeControl(new Android.Widget.EditText(Context));
            if (Control == null || e.NewElement == null)
                return;

            this.Control.Click += OnPickerClick;

            if (Element.NullableTime.HasValue)
                Control.Text = DateTime.Today.Add(Element.Time).ToString(Element.Format);
            else
                this.Control.Text = Element.PlaceHolder;

            this.Control.KeyListener = null;
            this.Control.FocusChange += OnPickerFocusChange;
            this.Control.Enabled = Element.IsEnabled;

        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName == Xamarin.Forms.TimePicker.TimeProperty.PropertyName ||
                e.PropertyName == Xamarin.Forms.TimePicker.FormatProperty.PropertyName)
                SetTime(Element.Time);
        }

        void OnPickerFocusChange(object sender, Android.Views.View.FocusChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.HasFocus)
            {
                ShowTimePicker();
            }
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (Control != null)
            {
                this.Control.Click -= OnPickerClick;
                this.Control.FocusChange -= OnPickerFocusChange;

                if (_dialog != null)
                {
                    _dialog.Hide();
                    _dialog.Dispose();
                    _dialog = null;
                }
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        void OnPickerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShowTimePicker();
        }

        void SetTime(TimeSpan time)
        {
            Control.Text = DateTime.Today.Add(time).ToString(Element.Format);
            Element.Time = time;
        }

        private void ShowTimePicker()
        {
            CreateTimePickerDialog(this.Element.Time.Hours, this.Element.Time.Minutes);
            _dialog.Show();
        }

        void CreateTimePickerDialog(int hours, int minutes)
        {
            NullableTimePicker view = Element;
            _dialog = new TimePickerDialog(Context, (o, e) =>
            {
                view.Time = new TimeSpan(hours: e.HourOfDay, minutes: e.Minute, seconds: 0);
                view.AssignValue();
                ((IElementController)view).SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
                Control.ClearFocus();

                _dialog = null;
            }, hours, minutes, true);

            _dialog.SetButton("ok", (sender, e) =>
            {
                SetTime(Element.Time);
                this.Element.Format = this.Element._originalFormat;
                this.Element.AssignValue();
            });

            _dialog.SetButton2("clear", (sender, e) =>
            {
                this.Element.CleanTime();
                Control.Text = this.Element.Format;
            });
        }
    }
```

On iOS project:

```
public class NullableTimePickerRenderer : TimePickerRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TimePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            var timePicker = (UIDatePicker)Control.InputView;
            timePicker.Locale = new NSLocale("no_nb");

            if (e.NewElement != null && this.Control != null)
            {
                this.UpdateDoneButton();
                this.AddClearButton();
                this.Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line;
                Control.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.LightGray.CGColor;
                Control.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;

                if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet)
                {
                    this.Control.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(25);
                }
            }

        }

        private void UpdateDoneButton()
        {
            var toolbar = (UIToolbar)Control.InputAccessoryView;
            var doneBtn = toolbar.Items[1];

            doneBtn.Clicked += (sender, args) =>
            {
                NullableTimePicker baseTimePicker = this.Element as NullableTimePicker;
                if (!baseTimePicker.NullableTime.HasValue)
                {
                    baseTimePicker.AssignValue();
                }
            };
        }

        private void AddClearButton()
        {
            var originalToolbar = this.Control.InputAccessoryView as UIToolbar;

            if (originalToolbar != null && originalToolbar.Items.Length <= 2)
            {
                var clearButton = new UIBarButtonItem("clear", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, ((sender, ev) =>
                {
                    NullableTimePicker baseTimePicker = this.Element as NullableTimePicker;
                    this.Element.Unfocus();
                    this.Element.Time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
                    baseTimePicker.CleanTime();

                }));

                var newItems = new List<UIBarButtonItem>();
                foreach (var item in originalToolbar.Items)
                {
                    newItems.Add(item);
                }

                newItems.Insert(0, clearButton);

                originalToolbar.Items = newItems.ToArray();
                originalToolbar.SetNeedsDisplay();
            }
        }
    }
```

This code works fine on iOS and Android version 8.1 or higher, but in lower version, this just not fire the event to set time, setting always the default time.

I'm also provided a git repo with the code, maybe, make easily understand my problem.
https://github.com/aismaniotto/Nullable24hTimePicker

Comment: Is the format proper? Are you sure the format at any point in time not empty?

Comment: Yes, the format is proper and it not be empty in any time. I used the debug and a lot of break points to evidence that. And, again, it is odd that works just fine on android 8.1, but lower, bugs.

Comment: could be a compatibility issue? Did you check with xamarin?

Comment: I search for something like that, but did not find anything. I put a repo with project sample, maybe that help to understand.

Comment: Please give us the link for that

Comment: I edited up there, but the link is https://github.com/aismaniotto/Nullable24hTimePicker

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. After more digging on code and debugging, I realize the problem was on OkButton implementation. On Android 8, apparently, the callback from the TimePickerDialog was called before the OkButton implementation e what was there, is ignored. On the older version, the OKButton implementation was called before and, for some reason, cancel the invocation of the callback.

That way, removing the OkButton implementation, the problem was solved... remembering that on the working version, was ignored anyway. Eventually, I will commit to the repository, to be registered.

Thanks a lot.